# When is convolution associative?

Tags: convolution, associativity

Convolution is associative on e.g. integrable function on $\mathbb{R},$ but not on distributions.

What about the convolution of measures on an unimodular group $G$?

Answer (score 2):

Convolution of finite Borel measures on a topological group is always well-defined and associative.

Comment: Thanks.Where is it written?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's the most general case but according to Kallenberg's *Foundations of Modern Probability*, convolution of measures (I suspect the measures need to be at least $\sigma$-finite here, it's not specified but the proof states that you should use Fubini's) on a *measurable group* (group endowed with a $\sigma$-algebra such that the group operations are measurable) is associative, so it's a bit more general than the answer above.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference